# Gather all data for same day into one row

Tags: python, matrix

The data I have can be simplified as:

```
Date;Temp
2019-06-20 00:00:00;18.44
2019-06-20 01:00:00;18.28
2019-06-20 07:00:00;18.23
2019-06-20 13:00:00;18.20
2019-06-21 02:00:00;18.48
2019-06-21 08:00:00;18.45
2019-06-21 14:00:00;18.36
2019-06-21 21:00:00;18.24
2019-06-22 01:00:00;18.15
2019-06-22 05:00:00;18.12
2019-06-22 12:00:00;18.06
2019-06-22 19:00:00;17.99
2019-06-23 00:00:00;17.35
2019-06-23 03:00:00;17.34
2019-06-23 08:00:00;17.31
2019-06-23 23:00:00;17.24
.
.
.
```

I would like to collect all the hourly temperatures for each day on the same row, and get a matrix something like:

```
2019-06-20 ;18.44;18.28;18.23;18.20
2019-06-21 ;18.48;18.45;18.36;18.24
2019-06-22 ;18.15;18.12;18.06;17.99
2019-06-23 ;17.35;17.34;17.31;17.24
.
.
.
```

I am using python and have tried with `for` loops and `df.groupby` without success (I would also need it to work for when the data changes month and year if possible). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have looked some more at df.groupby but still cannot get it into the format above. Is this the right function for this application or am I completely off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I achieve your goal using `for loop`.

I assume the file `data.txt` contains your data:

> **data.txt**

```
Date;Temp
2019-06-20 00:00:00;18.44
2019-06-20 01:00:00;18.28
2019-06-20 07:00:00;18.23
2019-06-20 13:00:00;18.20
2019-06-21 02:00:00;18.48
2019-06-21 08:00:00;18.45
2019-06-21 14:00:00;18.36
2019-06-21 21:00:00;18.24
2019-06-22 01:00:00;18.15
2019-06-22 05:00:00;18.12
2019-06-22 12:00:00;18.06
2019-06-22 19:00:00;17.99
2019-06-23 00:00:00;17.35
2019-06-23 03:00:00;17.34
2019-06-23 08:00:00;17.31
2019-06-23 23:00:00;17.24
```

Here is the code:

```
data = {}
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Date' not in line or 'Temp' not in line:
            k, v = line.split()
            temperature = v.split(';')[1]
            if k not in data:
                data[k] = [temperature]
            else:
                data[k].append(temperature)


for k, v in data.items():
    print("{} ;{}".format(k, ";".join(v)))
```

> **Outputs**

```
2019-06-20 ;18.44;18.28;18.23;18.20
2019-06-21 ;18.48;18.45;18.36;18.24
2019-06-22 ;18.15;18.12;18.06;17.99
2019-06-23 ;17.35;17.34;17.31;17.24
```

Comment: thank you! if you have the time, could you please explain what k, v = line.split() does?

Comment: Assume, `line = "hello world"`. So, `line.split()` will return `["hello", "world"]`. So, if you do: `k, v = line.split()`, you will obtain `k= "hello"` and `v = "world"`. It is a shortcut. You can check how the method `split()`works.

Comment: now i understand, thank you so much for your help and explanation!