# Python: error reading and manipulating DataFrame data

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame variable called "obsData", which has the structure:
[image]
I then use this variable as an input to a code (with [much help from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58902138/gather-all-data-for-same-day-into-one-row)) that sorts all hourly data into one row for each day using:

```
f = obsData

data = {}

for line in f:
    if 'Date' not in line or 'Temp' not in line:
        k, v, = line.split()                       # split line in 2 parts, v and k
        temperature = v.split(';')[1]
        if k not in data:
            data[k] = [temperature]
        else:
            data[k].append(temperature)


for k, v in data.items():
    outPut = "{} ;{}".format(k, ";".join(v))
```

My issue it that the variable "line" never manages to get past the first row of the data in "obsData". It only manages to read 'Date' but not the second column 'Temp'. As a consequence the split function tries to split 'Date' but since its only one value I get the error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I have tried to redefine "f" (i.e. "obsData") from a DataFrame into a ndarray or string using to make it easier for the code to work with the data:

```
f = f.values                                             # into ndarry                 

f = f.astype(str)                                        # into string try 1

f[['Date', 'Temp']] = f[['Date', 'Temp']].astype(str)    # into string try 2
```

But for some reason I don't understand I cant convert it. What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT for clarification: I get the error at the line with

```
k, v, = line.split()
```

Comment: You are trying to split a line based on the separator ";".
But you don't have any ";" in your line, so you can't access the `[1]` element of the `split()` function.

Comment: not really, since its two columns I would expect that Python already knows that I want to separate them into two different ones.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the expected output of your script? I don't really understand what you're trying to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing csv data it's best to use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('obsData.csv')
```

if you still need to loop check [itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I get the same error, but this time for the line: k, temperature = line.split()

Comment: can you `print(line)`

Comment: It just outputs: Date

Comment: I.e. the first cell, in the first row of "obsData" above.

Comment: is type(line) == class <tuple>?

Comment: No, I get that its <class 'str'>

Comment: then your split might be returning 3 values not 2, since your splitting on spaces, try `d, k, v = line.split()`

Comment: hmm, but the error I get is "expected 2, got 1." I also attached a new screenshot above if it may be helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203062/discussion-between-ksooklall-and-litmus).